# RowVectorXd not supported in rcppEigen?

Tags: rcpp, eigen

Mapping works fine with:

```
Map<Eigen::VectorXd> x(as<Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(y));
```

but not with:

```
Map<Eigen::RowVectorXd> x(as<Map<Eigen::RowVectorXd> >(y));
```

Is RowVectorXd not supported in RcppEigen?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

The code to enable this form of wrapping has been merged into the dev version of `RcppEigen`. Feel free to grab a copy via:

```
devtools::install_github("RcppCore/RcppEigen")
```

**Original:**

Per RcppEigen's [unit tests](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/51d8aa2c79c65fbc29a7135a4959bbfd9ec04161/inst/unitTests/runit.RcppEigen.R#L164-L179) and [exporters](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/51d8aa2c79c65fbc29a7135a4959bbfd9ec04161/inst/include/RcppEigenWrap.h#L206-L272), it [looks](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/51d8aa2c79c65fbc29a7135a4959bbfd9ec04161/inst/unitTests/runit.wrap.R#L19-L65) as if only VectorXd/VectorXi presently has an export class set up.

This needs to be added to the exporter class. Here is a [PR containing the fix](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/pull/32).

```
template<typename T>
class Exporter<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> > > {
    typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
    const static int RTYPE = ::Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype ;
    Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> vec ;

    public:
        Exporter(SEXP x) : vec(x) {
            if (TYPEOF(x) != RTYPE)
                throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong R type for mapped vector");
        }
        OUT get() {return OUT(vec.begin(), vec.size());}
    } ;
```

Since `RowVectorXd` is given as a row-vector of X decimals: `Matrix<double, 1, X>`. See [Matrix docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html)